# how IKE (Internet Key Exchange) protocol reacts to the replay attack?

Tags: key-management, attack-prevention, key-exchange, ike, replay-detection

I mean how IKE in any mode (quick,aggressive, main) responds to an attacker that tries to replay one or more messages?